# Detect android device inside an elevator

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to detect if a person is going up/down in elevator using android sensors.
But im not sure if it's feasible.
Is ther any way you can detect when an android device is inside an elevator using accelerometer or something similar?

**UPDATE**

I've tryied to use the pressure sensor and it seems like the pressure doesnt change at all !

Comment: Assuming that the user does not move the phone, broadly you'll have that if the acceleration on X axis is greater than -9.81m/s^2 the elevator is going down, while, if the acceleration on X axis is less than -9.81 m/s^2the elevator is going up.

Comment: Thanks but why specific on the x axis?

Comment: I think it depends in the orientation ... if the phone is flat then it's not Y axis

Comment: I was talking from a physical point of view. From the phone I think you can refer to the module of the three components (x, y, z)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect changes in height using the pressure sensor - however the pressure in the elevator may not actually change as expected due to factors like it being an enclosed space indoors.

You could also use the accelerometer to detect the initial acceleration and final deceleration of the elevator but all that completely depends on the orientation of the phone in their hand/pocket/bag.

It would be a very difficult task, and would require a particular environment to work effectively (phone always at the same orientation, no external factors changing the pressure in the elevator).

Comment: Thanks , the pressure sounds interesting. but the height from A point to B point in elevator isnt too big . so i guess the pressure sensor will not even notice it.